# Installing anaconda - "failed to create anaconda menus"

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I've been trying to install anaconda in the past few days, but with not luck.
I tried both the 2.7 and 3.6 version, but whenever I try to install it just says "failed to create anaconda menus", so the installation can't be completed.
I tried to look for a solution at other threads, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone around here have an idea on what to do?
If it somehow helps - I'm using the 32-bit version for windows XP.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

for windows XP, you need to install a version 2.2 of anaconda as said here :

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow long path names in Windows

See: https://lifehacker.com/windows-10-allows-file-names-longer-than-260-characters-1785201032

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Thanks!